HTML video fallback if the source doesn't exist
Is there a way to provide a fallback text if a HTML video source doesn't exist?
It would be best if the solution doesn't use JavaScript.
I know that adding a child to the video element works as a fallback if the source is not supported, but it doesn't work if the source doesn't exist.

You can't without JavaScript. Maybe consider using poster image instead?

Unfortunately poster is displayed even if the video loaded successfully, until the video starts playing. That's not desirable if the video doesn't autoplay.
